# .htaccess files are no longer working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

For some reason, `.htaccess` files have stopped working all of a sudden.

I checked `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` and `rewrite_module` is indeed loaded. However, putting random garbage in an `.htaccess` file is not causing any errors to show up in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - so the file is not being read at all.

Where do I begin looking for potential causes?

I'm using Apache2 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is getting evaluated in .htaccess files is controlled by the `AllowOverride` Configuration directive.

You may check the Apache documentation here: [Core - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Wow... Totally my mistake - somehow that got added to the configuration file. Thanks! It works now!